# XSD minLength not defined, what will be default minLegnth?

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

I have a xsd definition as below

```
<xs:simpleType name="ShortName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="3"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

I have given only maxLength and not defined minLength. Does it mean that I can have length of 'ShortName' can be 0,1,2,3 characters?

If I haven't explicitly set the minimum length, will the minimum length will be defaulted to 0 (minLength=0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_facets.asp

> minLength: Specifies the minimum
>   number of characters or list items
>   allowed. Must be equal to or greater
>   than zero.

If not specified I think default is Zero.

Answer (score 2):

From the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-maxLength):

> **Validation Rule: maxLength Valid**
>
> A value in a **value space** is facet-valid with respect to **maxLength**, determined as follows:
>
> > 1 if the {variety} is **atomic** then
> >
> > > 1.1 if {primitive type definition} is string or anyURI, then the length of the value, as measured in characters **must** be less than or equal to {value};
> > >
> > > 1.2 if {primitive type definition} is hexBinary or base64Binary, then the length of the value, as measured in octets of the binary data, **must** be less than or equal to {value};
> > >
> > > 1.3 if {primitive type definition} is QName or NOTATION, then any {value} is facet-valid.
> >
> > 2 if the {variety} is **list**, then the length of the value, as measured in list items, **must** be less than or equal to {value}

According to this definition, and in the absence of a minLength restriction, any length value which is less than or equal to the maxLength you define will be valid.  Ergo, zero will be the default minLength for a specification-compliant XML validator.